# How to build a keygen using flash builder

Tags: apache-flex, flash-builder

I'm currently building a keygen generator. It requires a request code (HWID)and a UDB ID to generate the activation code. However I need my USB ID number field to be able to detect alphabets as well so the it can generate an activation code with a mix of numbers and alphabets. Currently I cannot key in any alphabets to the USB ID field. Does anyone know how to fix this problem? Thanks. :)

*The number of the screen will generate different activation code.

Comment: Maybe this is a limitation of my understanding of the 'keygen' domain; but I do not understand what you are asking.

Comment: actually i wish to upload the picture but it was not allow. i wish to ask is there any example for me to refer how to build key generator to generate activation code, most of the example i found is using VB.net to build a key generator. thank you for your respond

Comment: Usually this is done on the server-side. Is there a specific reason you want to generate a token on the front-end (EG. offline enabled faux-security)?

Comment: Hi, I am going to deliver an Adobe AIR app to a customer. 
But it's my first delivery of any sort,so I have 
no experience whatsoever with licensing.so i would like to use flash builder to create a key generator to generate activation code.